# GeoServer stops working when trying to add vector tile layer

Tags: geoserver, vector-tiles, tomcat

I am trying to add vector tiles in GeoServer, but I am having a hard time accomplishing this.

I am using Tomcat and GeoServer version 2.16.1. I have installed the GeoServer extension for vector tiles support and tried to follow [this](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html) tutorial.

However after checking the vector tile formats and saving the layer, GeoServer stopped working and now doesn't start anymore.

The GeoServer logs are the following:

```
2020-02-29 19:21:28,873 INFO [geoserver.platform] - Falling back to embedded data directory: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver\data
2020-02-29 19:21:28,880 INFO [geoserver.platform] - Falling back to embedded data directory: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver\data
2020-02-29 19:21:29,140 INFO [org.geoserver] - GeoServer configuration lock is enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:29,182 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loading catalog...
2020-02-29 19:21:29,224 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'burg'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,224 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'capitals'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,224 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'cite_lakes'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,225 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'dem'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,225 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'generic'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,225 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'giant_polygon'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,225 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'grass'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,226 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'green'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,226 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'line'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,226 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'poi'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,226 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'point'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,226 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'polygon'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,226 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'pophatch'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,227 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'poly_landmarks'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,227 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'rain'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,227 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'population'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,228 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'raster'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,228 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'restricted'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,228 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'simple_roads'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,228 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'simple_streams'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,228 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'tiger_roads'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,229 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded default workspace cite
2020-02-29 19:21:29,240 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'burned_areas'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,242 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'it.geosolutions'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,243 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'nurc'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,243 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'cite'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,244 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'sf'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,244 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'opengeo'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,244 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'tiger'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,245 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'sde'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,246 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'topp'
2020-02-29 19:21:29,514 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'burned_areas', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,110 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'nuts2', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,118 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'nuts2'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,119 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'nuts3', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,119 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'nuts3'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,120 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'clc2018', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,121 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'clc2018'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,122 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'lau1', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,123 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'lau1'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,129 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'arcGridSample', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,147 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'Arc_Sample', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,148 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'Arc_Sample'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,148 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'img_sample2', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,282 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'Pk50095', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,282 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'Pk50095'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,283 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'mosaic', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,285 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'mosaic', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,285 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'mosaic'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,286 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'worldImageSample', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,288 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'Img_Sample', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,289 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'Img_Sample'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,290 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'opengeo', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,292 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'countries', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,292 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'countries'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,316 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'sf', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,330 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'archsites', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,331 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'archsites'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,332 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'bugsites', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,332 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'bugsites'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,333 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'restricted', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,334 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'restricted'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,335 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'streams', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,335 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'streams'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,336 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'roads', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,336 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'roads'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,337 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'sfdem', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,339 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'sfdem', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,339 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'sfdem'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,342 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'nyc', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,353 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'giant_polygon', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,354 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'giant_polygon'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,355 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tiger_roads', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,355 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tiger_roads'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,356 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'poi', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,356 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'poi'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,357 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'poly_landmarks', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,357 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'poly_landmarks'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,360 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'states_shapefile', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,362 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'states', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,362 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'states'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,364 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'taz_shapes', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,366 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_cities', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,367 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_cities'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,367 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_roads', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,367 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_roads'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,368 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_state_boundaries', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,368 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_state_boundaries'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,369 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_water_bodies', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,369 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_water_bodies'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,377 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'spearfish'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,378 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'tasmania'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,379 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'tiger-ny'
2020-02-29 19:21:30,380 INFO [org.geoserver] - Read catalog in 1.196 s
2020-02-29 19:21:30,443 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMTSInfoImpl-144418e5:17091f1963b:-7ffe', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,447 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'wcs', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,455 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'wfs', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,467 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'wms', enabled
2020-02-29 19:21:30,484 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Will look for 'geowebcache.xml' in directory 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver\data\gwc'.
2020-02-29 19:21:30,527 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc
2020-02-29 19:21:30,527 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc
2020-02-29 19:21:30,527 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc
2020-02-29 19:21:30,534 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - ********************************************************************************
2020-02-29 19:21:30,534 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - *** GWC configuration validation error: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'gwcConfiguration'.
2020-02-29 19:21:30,534 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - *** Will try to use configuration anyway. Please check the order of declared elements against the schema.
2020-02-29 19:21:30,534 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - ********************************************************************************
2020-02-29 19:21:30,571 INFO [config.XMLConfiguration] - Initializing GridSets from gwc
2020-02-29 19:21:30,572 INFO [config.XMLConfiguration] - Initializing layers from gwc
2020-02-29 19:21:30,600 INFO [gwc.layer] - Initializing GWC configuration based on GeoServer's Catalog
2020-02-29 19:21:30,600 INFO [gwc.layer] - GeoServer TileLayer store base directory is: gwc-layers
2020-02-29 19:21:30,600 INFO [gwc.layer] - Loading tile layers from gwc-layers
2020-02-29 19:21:30,622 INFO [gwc.layer] - Loaded 27 tile layers in 21.47 ms
2020-02-29 19:21:30,628 INFO [storage.BlobStoreAggregator] - BlobStoreConfiguration gwc contained no blob store infos.
2020-02-29 19:21:30,634 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - **************************************************************************************************************************************
2020-02-29 19:21:30,634 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - *** Found System environment variable TEMP set to C:\Windows\SERVIC~1\LOCALS~1\AppData\Local\Temp, using it as the default prefix. ***
2020-02-29 19:21:30,634 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - **************************************************************************************************************************************
2020-02-29 19:21:30,672 INFO [gwc.config] - Initializing GeoServer specific GWC configuration from gwc-gs.xml
2020-02-29 19:21:30,725 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Will look for 'geowebcache-diskquota.xml' in directory 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver\data\gwc'.
2020-02-29 19:21:30,730 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Will look for 'geowebcache-diskquota-jdbc.xml' in directory 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver\data\gwc'.
2020-02-29 19:21:30,731 INFO [diskquota.ConfigLoader] - DiskQuota configuration is not readable: gwc/geowebcache-diskquota.xml
2020-02-29 19:21:30,737 INFO [diskquota.ConfigLoader] - DiskQuota configuration is not readable: gwc/geowebcache-diskquota.xml
2020-02-29 19:21:30,738 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Setting up disk quota periodic enforcement task
2020-02-29 19:21:30,738 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - 0 layers configured with their own quotas. 
2020-02-29 19:21:30,745 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - 27 layers attached to global quota 500.0 MB
2020-02-29 19:21:30,768 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Disk quota periodic enforcement task set up every 10 SECONDS
2020-02-29 19:21:30,894 INFO [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Invoked setServletPrefix(gwc)
2020-02-29 19:21:30,903 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - Initializing GeoRSS poller in a background job...
2020-02-29 19:21:30,904 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - No enabled GeoRSS feeds found, poller will not run.
2020-02-29 19:21:30,962 INFO [wms.WMSService] - Will NOT recombine tiles for non-tiling clients.
2020-02-29 19:21:30,962 INFO [wms.WMSService] - Will proxy requests to backend that are not getmap or getcapabilities.
2020-02-29 19:21:32,669 INFO [geoserver.platform] - Falling back to embedded data directory: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver\data
2020-02-29 19:21:35,908 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
2020-02-29 19:21:35,909 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
2020-02-29 19:21:36,015 INFO [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Initialized with 1000 Max Entries, 300 seconds idle time, 600 seconds time to live and 3 concurrency level
2020-02-29 19:21:36,016 INFO [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Eviction Task created to run every 600 seconds
2020-02-29 19:21:36,102 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - destroy() invoked
2020-02-29 19:21:36,102 INFO [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - GeoWebCacheDispatcher.destroy() was invoked, shutting down.
2020-02-29 19:21:36,102 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Disk quota monitor shutting down...
2020-02-29 19:21:36,103 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Shutting down quota usage monitor...
2020-02-29 19:21:36,103 INFO [diskquota.QuotaUpdatesMonitor] - Shutting down quota usage monitor...
2020-02-29 19:21:36,103 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Shutting down quota statistics gathering monitor...
2020-02-29 19:21:36,103 INFO [diskquota.QueuedQuotaUpdatesConsumer] - Shutting down quota update background task due to InterruptedException
2020-02-29 19:21:36,104 INFO [diskquota.QueuedUsageStatsConsumer] - Shutting down quota update background task due to interrupted exception
2020-02-29 19:21:36,104 INFO [seed.SeederThreadPoolExecutor] - Initiating shut down for running and pending seed tasks...
2020-02-29 19:21:36,104 INFO [seed.SeederThreadPoolExecutor] - Seeder thread pool executor shut down complete.
2020-02-29 19:21:36,104 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageBroker] - Destroying StorageBroker
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add more information to your question, we need to know what you mean by "However after checking the vector tile formats and saving the layer," - which layer are you saving? does this work for say the topp:states layer? What does the log file say if you turn logging up to Debug?